# Need help understanding some code (Beginner)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to learn about while and for loops.  This function prints out the highest number in a list.  But, I'm not entirely sure how it works.  Can anyone break down how it works for me.  Maybe step by step and/or with a flowchart.  I'm struggling and want to learn.

```
def highest_number(list_tested):
    x=list_tested[0]
    for number in list_tested:
        if x<number:
            x=number
    print(x)

highest_number([1,5,3,2,3,4,5,8,5,21,2,8,9,3])
```

Comment: Describe what you do know about this function.

Comment: read it out loud ... theres not much to this

Comment: What it does is declare a function that takes an array as a parameter. In the function, x is initialized as the first element of the array. Then for every element in the array, it checks if x is less than that number (or if the number is greater than x) and if it is, it sets x to the bigger value. An answer to this can easily be found if you Google it.

Comment: "for number in list_tested, if x is less than number save number as x, finally at the end print x"

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! please take the time to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [what can I ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  As it is written your question would not be helpful to future viewers since it is only relevent to a very specific case. I'd recommend you use a tutorial or ask your professor.

Answer (score 4):

One of the most helpful things for understanding new code is going through it step by step:

[PythonTutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) has a visualizer: Paste in your code and hit visualize execution.

What this is going form the first to the last number and saying:
Is this new number bigger than the one I have? If so, keep the new number, if not keep the old number.

At the end, x will be the largest number.

Answer (score 1):

See my comments for step by step explanation of each line

```
def highest_number(list_tested): # function defined to take a list
    x=list_tested[0] # x is assigned the value of first element of list
    for number in list_tested: # iterate over all the elements of input list
        if x<number: # if value in 'x' is smaller than the current number
            x=number # then store the value of current element in 'x'
    print(x) # after iteration complete, print the value of 'x'

highest_number([1,5,3,2,3,4,5,8,5,21,2,8,9,3]) # just call to the function defined above
```

So basically, the function finds the largest number in the list by value.
It starts by setting the large number (x) as the first element of list, and then keeps comparing it to other elements of the list, until it finds an element which is greater than the largest number found till now (which is stored in x). So at the end, the largest value is stored in x.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are new to the programming world. Maybe you should start with some basic concepts, for/while loops are some among which, that would be helpful for you before jumping into something like this.

Here is one of the explanations you may easily find on the Internet http://www.teamten.com/lawrence/programming/intro/intro8.html